# Why dispesion relation in a 2d plane related to the poles of green's function?

Tags: optics, greens-functions, propagator, dispersion, metamaterials

I'm looking at a paper about deriving the dispersion relation in a metasurface, the paper claims that

> 'The modes supported by an anisotropic metasurface are provided by the poles of the Green’s
> function.'

I'm confused with it, can someone elaborate it?

title of that paper

'Hyperbolic metasurfaces: surface plasmons, light-matter interactions, and physical
implementation using graphene strips'